# What does this mean - ~/.my.cnf

Tags: linux, mysql-5.1, configuration, my.cnf

When I run `$ mysqld --verbose --help | less` I got information like

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/mysql/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

As per my understanding, At startup, mysql first look for **my.cnf** within `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` then within `/etc/my.cnf` and then finally `~/.my.cnf`.

- Am I correct?
- Which directory does this mean - `~/.my.cnf`?
- If a variable `x has value 100` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and again the same variable `x has value 200` in `etc/my.cnf`, What value will really apply?
  -

Comment: `~/.my.cnf` should be file .my.cnf inside home of starting user. so e.g. `/home/ursitesion/.my.cnf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.my.cnf` is `.my.cnf` file in your `home` directory. The meaning of tilde `~` in unix is current user's home directory.

The values from different configurations are overwritten. So `/etc/my.cnf` will overwrite was what defined in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, and `~/.my.cnf` will overwrite what was in previous files.

Comment: Will `~/.my.cnf` affect for all the users or for only that specific user?

Comment: only your user of course. Also I think it can only contain settings for the client as far as I remember.

Comment: Also, there is no such file in my installation. Even, there are multiple .xyz files are there.

Comment: Yes because it is not created by default, you need to create it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @edvinas. Can you advice about which file mysql read when start?

Comment: just edit `/etc/my.cnf` and you should be fine.

Comment: Value in `/etc/my.cnf` will be overwritten by `$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf`. In my case it is `$MYSQL_HOME` is `datadir` i.e. `/var/lib/mysql/`